# print scipy sparse matrix without skipping lines

Tags: python, numpy, printing, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to print all non zeros values of scipy sparse matrix, but it's print only head  and tail of the values.

I have tried to use *numpy* as well as *scipy* *set_printoptions*, but it's not make any changes.

For example:

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf, linewidth=np.inf, precision=5)

print(S_0)
```

When S_0 is a sparse matrix 4096 by 4096.

It's print:

```
  (0, 1)    0.05473236104737437
  (0, 63)   0.21776763895262571
  (0, 64)   0.11669233874304108
  (0, 65)   0.07099307125265637
  (0, 127)  0.16239160623342577
  (0, 4032) 0.15580766125695897
  (0, 4033) 0.03847165084209235
  (0, 4095) 0.27314367167182557
  (0, 0)    -0.09000000000000008
  (1, 1)    1.0
  (2, 1)    0.03201451256475778
  (2, 3)    0.2404854874352423
  (2, 65)   0.03313570631258726
  (2, 66)   0.2433307472199537
  (2, 67)   0.45352578812732014
  (2, 4033) 0.03089331881692829
  (2, 4034) 0.029169252780046343
  (2, 4035) 0.027445186743164394
  (2, 2)    -0.09000000000000008
  (3, 3)    1.0
  (4, 3)    0.1780272480832952
  (4, 5)    0.09447275191670479
  (4, 67)   0.09857505006040893
  (4, 68)   0.10065942747216487
  (4, 69)   0.10274380488392083
  : :
  (4071, 4071)  1.0
  (4072, 4072)  1.0
  (4073, 4073)  1.0
  (4074, 4074)  1.0
  (4075, 4075)  1.0
  (4076, 4076)  1.0
  (4077, 4077)  1.0
  (4078, 4078)  1.0
  (4079, 4079)  1.0
  (4080, 4080)  1.0
  (4081, 4081)  1.0
  (4082, 4082)  1.0
  (4083, 4083)  1.0
  (4084, 4084)  1.0
  (4085, 4085)  1.0
  (4086, 4086)  1.0
  (4087, 4087)  1.0
  (4088, 4088)  1.0
  (4089, 4089)  1.0
  (4090, 4090)  1.0
  (4091, 4091)  1.0
  (4092, 4092)  1.0
  (4093, 4093)  1.0
  (4094, 4094)  1.0
  (4095, 4095)  1.0
```

I want it to print **all** the values

Any ideas?

Comment: That's not a regular numpy array display, so the `set_pribtoptions` does not apply.  Why do you need to print all elements?  Such a print is supposed to give an idea of the structure,.  It's not meant for reproducing the matrix.

Comment: Try using scipy.io.mmwrite and piping it to sys.stdout.

Comment: @hpaulj, thank you for the explanation. I need to examine few matrix with complex structure. I write all elements to make it easy to explain, but basically I need about 100-200 rows each print

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and setting numpy print options did not work. The following worked for me. (tested for scipy version 1.5.3 and 1.8.1)

```
import numpy as np
# ...
# let's say your S_0 is your sparse matrix, then this helps:
S0.maxprint = np.inf
print(S0) # now prints all entries
```

---

According to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html?highlight=coo#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix) there is a function `getmaxprint()`. Looking up the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.8.1/scipy/sparse/_base.py#L259-L261) it just returns the attribute `maxprint` of the class, which by default is 50. So overwriting it with infinity will result in no limit for printing. Also you can provide it in the constructor of your sparse matrix.
You can also see how the string for printing is created when looking at the function `__str__` of the class `spmatrix` which is the base class of all sparse matrices of scipy ([link to code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/4cf21e753cf937d1c6c2d2a0e372fbc1dbbeea81/scipy/sparse/_base.py#L312))